# How to suppress null with single row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a oracle table like

```
Name   Sal   Bonus 
ABC    400   null
ABC    null   5
```

How to make it single row and remove null data

```
Name   Sal   Bonus
ABC    400    5
```

Please suggest. Using oracle sql.

Comment: What if there's another ABC row, with Sal = 250?

Answer (score 0):

If you have just two rows, you can use group by clause. And sum values inside select statement.

```
SELECT T.NAME,SUM(NVL(T.SAL,0))AS Sal,SUM(NVL(T.SAL,0)) AS Bonus
FROM TABLE t 
GROUP BY T.NAME
```

Here the result:

```
Name   Sal   Bonus
ABC    400    5
```

Comment: Do you really need those NVL here?

Comment: In fact, here in this case you can do it without nvl() function. I wasn't sure whether the group by clause ignore null values or not. That's why I answered in this way. I tried it without NVL() function, I see Null values are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

select name, max(sal), max(bonus)
from Table
group by name